# Display Login Screen When User Is Not Logged In Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to show the user a login screen when opening the app but I don't know how to display it. It currently just displays my home screen and I want it to display my login screen instead.
I would appreciate every answer.

Here is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_background">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/indigo_600"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="@string/username"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userIconToolbar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/user_pb_default" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_highlight"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ShitChat"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_credentials"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_credentials"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_recent_message_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_recent_message_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/indigo_400"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_credentials"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_recent_direct_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recent Direct Messages"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="#D4D4D4"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recent_recycler_direct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_recent_groups_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recent Group Messages"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="#D4D4D4"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recent_recycler_groups"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbarUserIconClick();

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_direct, R.id.navigation_groups, R.id.navigation_settings).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

        if (!isUserLoggedIn())
        {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            navView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private boolean isUserLoggedIn()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void toolbarUserIconClick()
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userIconToolbar);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Link To Profile Settings Here
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your startDestination in **mobile_navigation.xml** file is **HomeFragment**

Change your startDestination to **LoginFragment** and then navigate to the **HomeFragment** when the user is logged in.

You can read more about android navigation from here - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: But I don't have the login in the navbar and I don't want to show it on the navbar. I just want it to be the only screen when the user is not logged in.